Is a 考え物 *always* a bad idea?
I was reading some definitions for the word 考え物, here is its entry in 新明解国語辞典:

㊀その是非などについて慎重に考えて△みる（から決す）べき事柄。
「情勢を見るに、今ここで勝負に出るのは━だ」

I understand that this word is used frequently in the context of pushing someone or oneself to reconsider something.
However, in most of the examples I see this in, there seems to be little room for a 考え物 to ever turn out to be an okay idea in the first place. This is different I feel than simply "a matter for careful consideration".
Consider this example sentence and the English translation it came with:

金持ちになるのも考えものだ
One must think twice before getting rich.

In English, "think twice" is almost always used when the speaker wants to emphasize how one's actions could lead to a negative result, rather than simply "Becoming rich is something to consider deeply", which could emphasize a potential list of pros and cons of becoming rich.
I feel like 考え物 only occupies the first definition rather than talking about pros and cons of the proposed idea. Indeed, this hinative answer uses 「良い考えだと思わない」 in their definition, which I feel implies a more negative nuance than the 新明解 definition (which includes 是非) would imply. Is this word only used in regards to bad ideas?

I think "must think twice" captures the nuance of 考え物だ very well. 考え物だ always focuses on the negative aspect or potential risk of something, but this doesn't necessarily mean your final decision must also be negative.
In the case of 金持ちになるのも考えものだ, this means there are certain risks in becoming rich, and you must think twice before pursuing wealth. However, this is not the same as 金持ちになるのは良い考えではない, either. 考え物だ implies that, if you still want to become rich after careful consideration, it's fine to do so.
